# Jacoco not analyzing inline extension functions of interface

Tags: android, kotlin, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

I have following interface with an extension function in an Android project

```
interface MyInterface {  
    fun aMethod(): String
}

private inline fun MyInterface.myExtensionFunction(
    aString: String?,
) = with(aString) {
    //Some actions
}
```

Although the extension function has tests, when generating the Jacoco test report I see 0% coverage in this file. When running the tests with coverage using Android studio I see the right coverage.

An important thing to mention, non-inline extension functions appear to be covered in both the Jacoco and Android Studio report.

How should I set up Jacoco to include `myExtensionFunction` tests in the coverage report?